# Percentage from Total size after GROUP BY python

Tags: python, pandas

```
   code_module  final_result

    AAA      Distinction            44
                  Fail              91
                 Pass              487
                Withdrawn          126
```

THIS IS AN OUTCOME OF PYTHON CODE

```
 studentInfo.groupby(['code_module','final_result']).agg({'code_module':[np.size]})
```

- I want to calculate the percentage of each final_result from the total
- the math is  AAA.pass/AAA.total
- the total is the sum of all the numbers above.

Comment: I'm not sure you can aggregate on something used in `groupby`. Currently you have `'code_module'` working in both operations.

Comment: Are you using pandas?

Comment: yes i'm using panda

Comment: code_module and fina_result are name of column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) with parameter `normalize`:

```
s1 = studentInfo.groupby('code_module')['final_result'].value_counts(normalize=True)
print (s1)
code_module  final_result
AAA          Pass            0.651070
             Withdrawn       0.168449
             Fail            0.121658
             Distinction     0.058824
Name: final_result, dtype: float64
```

Or divide your simplify solution with [`DataFrameGroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.size.html)  by `sum` per first level of `MultiIndex`

```
s = studentInfo.groupby(['code_module','final_result']).size()
s2 = s.div(s.sum(level=0), level=0)
print (s2)
code_module  final_result
AAA          Distinction     0.058824
             Fail            0.121658
             Pass            0.651070
             Withdrawn       0.168449
dtype: float64
```

Difference between solutions is `value_counts`  return output `Series` in descending order so that the first element is the most frequently-occurring element, `size` not.